# How to extract output information from wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have one wsdl. I have no idea in this area. After doing a lot of research I was able to extract java classes from the wsdl using the following command in cmd.

```
md generated
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20"\bin\wsimport -keep -d generated https://wsdlurl?wsdl
```

But now I have no idea what to do with these classes. When I try to look into these classes through netbeans, some of them gives error like `annotation type not applicable on this kind of declaration` and `duplicate class`.

Can anyone please guide me how can I make use of these classes. Or if there is any other better way to get the output out of the wsdl. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some programme like `Oxygen XML Editor 17.1`or you can add url in browser like this:

```
    https://wsdlurl?wsdl
```

You can generate some Java that represents the client's view of the Web Service and then invoke that Java. in this link article which explains some of the detail.
[
accepted
You need to generate some Java that represents the client's view of the Web Service and then invoke that Java. Here's an article which explains some of the detail.

[Generating client from WSDL](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf)
For more info go to [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx)

Comment: Yeah with this I get the methods which are mentioned in xml format. I already converted those methods in .java and .class files. I need to know the next step. What should I do with these classes?